# Element not detecting click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating HTML dynamically through javascript and have 2 glyphs enclosed within a table cell.  The pencil glyph responds correctly however my code for the delete does not and I am not sure why.

This is the rendered HTML

```
<span id="edit-dp" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-action-url="/Settings/GetDatapoint" data-id="3"></span>
<span id="delete-dp" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-id="3"></span>
```

and here is my javascript code to tie the event up to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#delete-dp').click(function (event) {
      alert('pressed');
      //add the datapoint ID to the array to be serialised to JSON and then stored in a html hidden field
      deletedDatapoints.push($(this).data('id'));
  });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.on()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#delete-dp', function (event) {
        alert('pressed');
        //add the datapoint ID to the array to be serialised to JSON and then stored in a html hidden field
        deletedDatapoints.push($(this).data('id'));
    });
});
```

You could scope it to the closest parent that is not dynamically generated to be more efficient than `document`.

Comment: This uses "event delegation". The problem that OP is experiencing is related to the element not existing when the JavaScript is run. Delegation avoids this by using event propagation.

Comment: @area28 I have no idea why but this works, thanks!  Can you explain why this works as opposed to why my first approach did not work?

Comment: Check out [this doc](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) about event delegation. This explains it very well.

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamicly added events use

```
$('#delete-dp').on('click',function(event){
    //do your stuff
});
```

Comment: that still doesn't seem to work.