# accessing html element after it was inserted by DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I have a Jquery function that when a button add_entry is clicked, inserts a 'save button' inside the page like this; the button shows up, so I assume that part is working.

```
 $("#add_entry").click(function(){
    $("#add_entry").hide();
    $('#status').append(<button class="save_entry">Test</button>);
});
```

then I have yet another function that is supposed to be called when aforementioned save button is clicked:

```
 $(".save_entry").click(function(){
    alert("i dont work :/");
});
```

which makes me wonder...

a) How does DOM manipulation actually work? - Since the jquery part is wrapped into the $document.ready() method does that mean i cant access 'on-the-fly' created elements like that ?

b) when injecting elements with DOM manipulation, they never appear in the source... why?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Duplicate of lots of others [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119535/element-not-detecting-click-event/31119601#31119601)

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically added elements, you need to bind events like following.

```
$(document).on("click", ".save_entry", function(){
    alert("i will work now");
});
```

As suggested by Rory, you can also bind the event to **#status**.

```
$("#status").on("click", ".save_entry", function(){
    alert("i will work now");
});
```

For reference - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You should bind the primary selector to the nearest static parent, in this case `#status`, instead of filling the `document` with events.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I agree with you. Updating answer.

Comment: still not really understanding why this works, but wow that was fast !

Comment: @AndreasGoetze for a full explanation of what the problem is, and why this solutions works, see the answer I marked as duplicate.

Comment: thanks guys! didnt find the right keywords i guess